# Grails - Rendering JSON from multiple named configurations

Tags: json, grails, grails-2.0

I'm wondering how to render JSON from multiple named configurations?

For example, say I have 2 named marshallers in 2 separate named configurations. Let's say marshaller 1 is used to marshall User objects and its configuration is named "user" and marshaller 2 is used to marshall Hotel objects and its configuration is named "hotel". Now suppose I want to render both User and Hotel objects from a controller. For rendering a single object I'd normally just do something like:

```
JSON.use("user) { respond User.list() }
```

I'm wondering how I'd update this to render both User and Hotel objects as JSON since the use method only takes a single configuration name?

Comment: Ignoreing the named config for a moment, how would you be rendering both objects? Would hotel render as part of the user object or vice versa? Would they be rendered as separate objects in a single map?

Comment: I'm thinking of the use case where they would be rendered as separate objects in a simple map.